# How to combine all rows with same data in column?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Let's say I have a table name receipts.  Then the table has a receipt_num, product, and price.

Let's say I have a table that looks like this.

```
receipt_num | item | price
    --------+------+------
    6       | a    | 10
    6       | b    | 15
    1       | c    | 7
```

What SQL query can I use to get something like this.

```
receipt_num | price
    --------+------+------
    6       | 25
    1       | 7
```

Essentially I am combining all the rows with the same receipt_num, excluding the item column and adding up the total price.

I have tried using SELECT receipt_num, price FROM  receipts.
I am very new at this so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is an aggregation query -- a very basic SQL operation:

```
select receipt_num, sum(price)
from receipts
group by receipt_num;
```

I strongly encourage you to find tutorials, books, lessons or something so you can learn the fundamental ideas in SQL.